# Java int can't be changed because lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I am trying to make a Java tic tac toe game and am having some issues with the code.

What I want to do is just increment an int when the user clicks a button.

The problem is is that the compiler says `"Error:local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"`. What I understand this to mean is that I can only create an value and not redefine it in the same method but I am new to java and have no idea for a work around.

I am thinking of a work around by having multiple classes but this is overly complicated and I just want to add to the int like in python. If anyone has any idea on how to do this or a work around then it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my program

```
public class TicTacToe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //Some code here

        //this is Cerateing all the buttons
        //the buttons are formated in a 3X3 array for a total of 9 buttons
        Button B1 = new Button();
        //More buttons

        //this sets the size of the button

        //this is the int that tracks what button the user has pressed
        //this is my value
        int User = 0;

        //this gets if the user has clicked any of the buttons shold in therory do somthing
        B1.setOnAction((event) -> {
            B1.setText("X");
            //this is where I want to add to an value
            User++;
        });

        //More code

        System.out.println(User);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use an `AtomicInteger` or `IntegerProperty`.

Comment: The easy solution, is just to make User a field in the class, instead of a local variable. (And call it user. all variables should start with lower case. Upper case is for class names).

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions please!

Comment: Java does allow one to add to integers. However, you're using a lambda expression, which is special because it escape outside the method. This means that if that lambda is called somewehre outside your method, it will attempt to change the value of the local variable `User`, even though the doesn't exist. This is why you can't change local variables in lambdas. Read the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify where you got error, but this part should give an error:

```
int User = 0;

B1.setOnAction((event) -> {
    B1.setText("X");
    User++;
});
```

The `User` variable either needs to be a field, a wrapper like `AtomicInteger` or `new int[1]`, or a final object. Here are a couple of ways to get around this. First of all, you can just make `User` a field.

```
private int User = 0;
```

Then don't declare it in the method. Another thing you can do is make a `new int[1]`.

```
int User = new int[]{0};

B1.setOnAction((event) -> {
    B1.setText("X");
    User[0] ++;
});
```

Then when accessing it, you can use `User[0]`. Another way is using `AtomicInteger`. I don't really like it that much, but here is how you can use it anyways:

```
AtomicInteger User = new AtomicInteger(0);

B1.setOnAction((event) -> {
    B1.setText("X");
    User.incrementAndGet();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much I used a field and Got it to work thanks for taking the time to help me out.